# How to repeat the cellmerging in XLSX with openTBS?

Tags: xlsx, opentbs, tinybutstrong

Let me try to describe the problem in words. I have a headline in my array which should be centered in two merged cells. When opentbs is looping throug my array, only the first headline is in a merged cell, for all upcoming headlines the cellmerging gets lost.

The Array is similar to this:

```
$data = [
    'name' => 'district one',
    'streets' => [
        [
            'name' => 'first street',
            'description' => 'first text',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'second street',
            'description' => 'second text',
        ]
    ],
    'name' => 'district two',
    'streets' => [
        [
            'name' => 'third street',
            'description' => 'third text',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'fourth street',
            'description' => 'fourth text',
        ]
    ],
]
```

The cell structure i want to reach is like this:

[Cellstructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDkuj.jpg)

and this is the code of template:

```
[data;block=begin;sub1=streets] 
[data.name;block=tbs.row]   
[data_sub1;block=begin] 
[data_sub1.name]    [data_sub1.description]
[data_sub1;block=end]   
[data;block=end]
```

here is the templatecode and the result in one img:

[templatecode an result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COHJy.jpg)

How to repeat the cellmerging with openTBS?

Comment: OpenTBS does not support cellmerging in XLSX for now (last version is OpenTBS 1.9.10). This is because XLSX save the cellmerging info appart of the sheet so it make difficult to merge both the sheet and the cellmerging info together. Nevertheless it is in the plan. The problem is only with XLSX, not DOCX.

Comment: Does openTBS support image reapeating, as in my example an image for each district? @Skrol29

Comment: Unfortunately OpenTBS does not support image repeating in XLSX for now. It's all ok and easy with DOCX or PPTX, but in XLSX an image is not attached to a cell, an image is attached to a worksheet so there is noway to define a TBS block that includes the image.